# Looking for mongodb design pattern regarding full collection replacement weekly

Tags: mongodb

Noob to mongodb here... Coming from ETL in Oracle background.  Wondering if you can suggest a design pattern to employ.  Will be loading weekly a full dataset of phone numbers and other fields. Phone number will be the primary interested key to lookup by. Instead of doing some sort of delta (determine what to add/change/delete) can I just create a new collection with the new dataset... and then inform my API to start using the new collection name...  But would I name collections like:  phones_YYYYMMMDD or or is there something more slick to employ.

edit:  Say that I wont be doing updates... and only need to remove no-longer-needed phone records and add missing phone records...  Is there a map reduce or something like that to determine these two condiditions (#1 remove phones, #2 insert new phones).  Recall I'm from the Oracle relational background, and in that env, I'd load the new dataset, and using joins to figure out the to-be-deleted and to-be-inserted recs.

Comment: I would definitely use bulk writes in your use case.  As you mentioned if you are reloading the entire set you may need to recreate indexes and this can take some effort by the system.  There are no slick tools for utilizing the "current" collection.  If you could identify the deltas it would probably be a faster operation, assuming updates don't include replacing the entire record each time, but instead only updates part of the record.  Another consideration is the effect this load has on replication and any clients issuing operations with specific read or write concerns while loading.

Comment: You can name collections as you posted (also see [Collection Naming Restrictions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#mongodb-limit-Restriction-on-Collection-Names)). You can also access the collection by its variable name. _Some things to think about_: How much data are you loading into a new collections? Indexes on the collection fields? These occupy space. Does this loading process affect the server and the current operations? etc.